# Vertices coloring in Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

For graph $A$ and $B$, define $A \times B$ to have vertex set $V(A) \times V(B)$, with $(a,b)$ adjacent to $(c,d)$ if $a$ is joined to $c$ in $A$, $b$ is joined to $d$ in $B$(assume they are not the same). We need to show that $\chi(A \times B)=\min\{\chi(A),\chi(B)\}.$

Could anyone give me some idea on this problem? I would assume it is a easy problem but have no clue to solve.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Start with a minimal vertex coloring of $G$. Extend it to $G\times H$ by giving each vertex $\langle a,b\rangle$ the same color as $a$. Show that this is a legitimate vertex coloring of $G\times H$. This shows that $\chi(G\times H)\le\chi(G)$. A similar argument shows that $\chi(G\times H)\le\chi(H)$, so it only remains to be shown that $\chi(G\times H)$ cannot be smaller than both $\chi(G)$ and $\chi(H)$.

This, however is [Hedetniemi’s conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedetniemi's_conjecture), which apparently is open, so you can’t be expected to prove it. If you modify the definition of the product graph to say that $\langle a,b\rangle$ is adjacent to $\langle c,d\rangle$ if $\langle a,b\rangle\ne\langle c,d\rangle$, $a$ is adjacent *or equal* to $c$, and $b$ is adjacent *or equal* to $d$, then you can prove it by noting that $G\times H$ contains subgraphs isomorphic to $G$ and to $H$.

Comment: The last sentence may fail under some circumstances, for example if $G$ has edges and $H$ has no edges

Comment: @Hagen: You’re right; in fact the result isn’t actually known. I need to modify that.